# Function doesn't seem to return true

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTables plugin and the colorbox plugin.  I am trying to have my function return true if the .post is a success.

```
jQuery('.msg_delete').live('click', function () {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        if (deleteMessage(aData[6]) == true) {
            jQuery.colorbox.close();
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(nTr);
        }
        return false;
    });

function deleteMessage(messageID) {
    jQuery.post('ajax/msg_functions.asp', { action: 'delete', messageid: messageID }, function (data) {

    })
    .success(function () { return true; })
    .error(function () { alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support"); })
    ;
}
```

Right now it correctly does the post.  I know this because the message is deleted.  So I assume it goes to the `.success` and I would think would now return true.  But it doesn't seem to be doing that.

It never seems to go to the `colorbox.close()` or `fnDeleteRow.`  Can anyone see what I am missing here?

Comment: The `A` in `AJAX` stands for asynchronous :)

Comment: @XyanEwing I'm sure you're saying something.  But I'm just not sure what you're trying to tell me.  Is what I am doing above not AJAX?  Or is what I am trying to do not possible with AJAX?

Comment: I was being cryptic because I knew that someone would be much faster and give a much better answer than me.  Like KevinB below :)

Comment: @JamesWilson That depends on what part you are talking about. It is not possible to return out of one scope from within a child scope the way you are doing it, however it is possible to do what you are trying to do with ajax if you organize it properly.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!  You guys make me better and better every day. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your return only returns out of the current function which is the anonymous function you passed into `$.ajax`.

Your code will not work the way it is currently organized, working on an example.

```
jQuery('.msg_delete').live('click', function() {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
    deleteMessage(aData[6]).done(function(){
        jQuery.colorbox.close();
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(nTr);
    });
    return false;
});

function deleteMessage(messageID) {
    return jQuery.post('ajax/msg_functions.asp', {
        action: 'delete',
        messageid: messageID
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support");
    });
}​
```

Also, `.success` is depreciated, use `.done`

Edit:

For completeness, you could have used `async:false` and stored `true` or `false` in a variable and then returned that from your function, however it is less efficient and not recommended due to the fact that `async:false` pauses code execution and user interaction.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you very much.  Guess there still is a lot to learn about jQuery for me. :)

Comment: is there any reason .on doesn't work with this method?  I tried to change it from .live to .on and it doesn't work any more.

Comment: You probably aren't using the correct syntax for `.on`, try `jQuery(document).on('click','.msg_delete',...`

Comment: Hrm, I'll just leave it to .live.  When I changed it to the above method it deletes the message as soon as the TR row is clicked which is very strange behavior.

Comment: That is strange, considering your `.live` call maps directly to the `.on` code i posted!

Comment: Yeah.  This seems to be the only method I cannot update to .on.  Which means I must have some code higher up that doesn't like something.  I'll figure it out.  Thanks again for your help! :)